# Submit onBlur function only when the input is valid

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, formsy-react

I'm using input from formsy-semantic-ui-react for form validation and how can i run the onBlur function only when the field is valid?

There is a `isValid()` function in formsy-react, `this.props.isValid()` but how i call this function in the input from formsy-semantic-ui-react?

how i can do something like, `onBlur={isValid() ? this.updateValue : null}`?

```
<Form.Input
    instantValidation={false}
    name="input1"
    label="Input 1"
    validations="isNumeric"
    validationErrors={{
    isNumeric: "Enter numeric only"
    }}
    errorLabel={errorLabel}
    onBlur={this.updateValue}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a behavior like this you'll have to create your own component that manages this. Using the `withFormsy` higher-order component you'll get access to the `isValid` function.

This is just an example, but it should get you what you want

```
import { withFormsy } from 'formsy-react';
const MyInput = withFormsy(({ onValidUpdate, ...otherProps }) => {
    const onBlur = (event) => {
        if (otherProps.isValid()) {
            onValidUpdate()
        }
    }

    return (
        <Form.Input {...otherProps} onBlur={onBlur} />
    )
})
```

And then use the component like

```
const onValidUpdate = () => console.log('this will only be called when valid')

<MyInput
    name="email"
    label="Email"
    validations="isEmail"
    validationErrors={{ isEmail: 'Email not valid' }}
    errorLabel={errorLabel}
    onValidUpdate={onValidUpdate}
/>
```